# Issue with stopping voice after clicking the stop button in the Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, frontend, azure-cognitive-services

I am currently using the **'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk'** to generate speech by clicking a button in the Angular frontend. I want to stop the speech when clicking another button, but I haven't found a proper solution for that. Can you assist me with this matter? Below is my code

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ApplicationSettings } from 'app/modules/types/appConfiguration';
import { AppConfigService } from 'app/services/app.config.service';
import * as sdk from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SpeechService {
  private appSettings: ApplicationSettings;

  constructor(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
    this.appSettings = appConfigService.getAppSettings();
  }

  textToSpeech(languageKey, voiceKey, text: string) {
    const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
      this.appSettings.speechServices.key,
      this.appSettings.speechServices.region
    );

    speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = languageKey;
    speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = voiceKey;
    const synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(
      speechConfig,
      sdk.AudioConfig.fromDefaultSpeakerOutput()
    );

    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text);
  }
  
  stopTextSpeech() : void {
   //Need to implment the stop speaking code in here
  }
}
```

Note : I am using "microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk": "^1.34.0" version and the angular version is 15

Answer (score 0):

Use `recognizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync()` method. Please [refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer?view=azure-node-latest#stopcontinuousrecognitionasync-------void---e--string-----void-)
[startContinuousRecognitionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer?view=azure-node-latest#microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk-speechrecognizer-stopcontinuousrecognitionasync)

```js
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApplicationSettings } from 'app/modules/types/appConfiguration';
    import { AppConfigService } from 'app/services/app.config.service';
    import * as sdk from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk';
    import { SpeechRecognizer } from 'microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk;
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root',
    })
    export class SpeechService {
      private appSettings: ApplicationSettings;
      private _synthesizer: SpeechRecognizer;
    
      constructor(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
        this.appSettings = appConfigService.getAppSettings();
      }
    
      textToSpeech(languageKey, voiceKey, text: string) {
        const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
          this.appSettings.speechServices.key,
          this.appSettings.speechServices.region
        );
    
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisLanguage = languageKey;
        speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = voiceKey;
        this._synthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(
          speechConfig,
          sdk.AudioConfig.fromDefaultSpeakerOutput()
        );
    
        this._synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text);
      }
      
      stopTextSpeech() : void {
       //Need to implment the stop speaking code in here
       this._synthesizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync(this.stopRecognizer.bind(this);
      }
      
      stopRecognizer() {
        this._synthesizer.close();
        this._synthesizer = undefined;
        console.log('stopped');
      }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the time to answering this question , i have added this code ,but i am getting an  issue 
"core.mjs:8506 ERROR TypeError: this._synthesizer.stopContinuousRecognitionAsync is not a function" any idea about this

Comment: please check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speechrecognizer?view=azure-node-latest#stopcontinuousrecognitionasync-------void---e--string-----void-